# How to load a tf.keras model which is trained with pure tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I have trained a model (which is built with tf.keras) with pure tensorflow. I have saved the model using `model.save(model_150.h5)` (as it is a keras model). 
Here is my model:

```
conv_1_1 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
conv_1_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_1_1)
conv_1_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_1_1_bn)

pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size= 2, strides = 2)(conv_1_1_do)

conv_4_1 = SeparableConv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_1)
conv_4_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_4_1)
conv_4_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_4_1_bn)

pool_4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size= 2, strides = 2)(conv_4_1_do)

conv_5_1 = SeparableConv2D(filters = 1024, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_4)
conv_5_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_5_1)
conv_5_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_5_1_bn)

upconv_1 = upconv_concat(conv_5_1_do, conv_4_1_do, n_filter=512, pool_size=2, stride=2) 

conv_6_1 = SeparableConv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upconv_1)
conv_6_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_6_1)
conv_6_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_6_1_bn)


upconv_2 = upconv_concat(conv_6_1_do, conv_1_1_do, n_filter=64, pool_size=2, stride=2) 

conv_9_1 = SeparableConv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upconv_2)
conv_9_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_9_1)
conv_9_1_do = Dropout(droprate)(conv_9_1_bn)


ae_output = Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=1, strides = (1,1), activation="softmax")(conv_9_1_do)
```

I initially defined the model like this:

```
e_model = Model(input_img, ae_output)
```

Now I needed some custom training. So I trained the model with pure tensorflow like this:

Here is my loss function

```
def cut_loss(original_image):
    ypred = e_model(original_image)
    ...
    ...
    #do some computations and calculate some custom loss
    ...
    return loss
```

Here is my optimizer

```
#optimizer    
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=e_lr).minimize(cut_loss(original_image))
```

Here is my training loop

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variable_initializer())
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print("epoch:", epoch)
        count = 0
        batch_start_index = 0
        while (count != num_batches):
            X_train_batch = X_train[batch_start_index : batch_start_index+batch_size] #send a batch of input images of size (batchsize, 224, 224, 1)
            _, train_loss = sess.run([opt,loss], feed_dict={original_image: X_train_batch})
            batch_start_index+=batch_size
            count+=1
        print("Train loss after ", str(epoch), "is", str(train_loss))
```

After the training, I saved the model and I restarted my jupyter kernel. when I tried loading the model from the h5 file like this

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
e_model = load_model('model_150.h5')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
UserWarning: No training configuration found in save file: the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Is it just bad to train the model using tensorflow and save the model using `model.save()` function from `tf.keras`?

Please let me know if any additional details are required. Thanks!

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning that `model.compile` was never called on the model.

Comment: but I'm not getting the model predictions correctly. The loaded model doesn't perform like it is trained. The outputs are the same as that of the initial model.

Comment: I am getting the same error. I think it hasn't been solved yet? :(